# Ширина и высота трансформированного элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть трансформируемый пользователем элемент(синий прямоугольник), его можно повернуть с помощью transform:rotate() и масштабировать с помощью transform:scale(). Как получить iX и iY?
element.getBoundingClientRect().width возвращает диагональ, равную bx

Comment: при повороте длина стороны не меняется. А меняется только при transform:scale(). Нельзя просто умножить длину стороны на scale?  А scale при необходимости можно достать через style dom-элемента